# Cowpatibility USACO

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, combinatorics

I'm confused with the USACO Cowpatibility solution explanation and code.

The problem is defined here: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=862.

Their solution is defined here: http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_cowpatibility_gold_dec18.html.

I know their linear solution requires the property of inclusion and exclusion (PIE), and I understand this property, but I am confused about how they implemented it. I'm looking for an explanation of these lines:

> "This motivates the following inclusion-exclusion solution: for every subset of flavors, count how many pairs of cows that like all flavors within each subset. We add all the counts for subsets of size 1, then to avoid double-counting, we subtract all the counts for subsets of size 2. We then add all the counts of subsets of size 3, subtract all the counts of subsets of size 4, and add the counts of subsets of size 5."

How do they determine every possible subset, and what are these subsets? Why are there only 31N subsets? It would also be helpful if someone gives examples of what the subsets would be for their sample case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They generated and stored subsets in order to keep track of the number of pairs of cows with 1 flavor in common, 2 flavors in common, 3 flavors in common, 4 flavors in common, and all 5 flavors in common. To do this, they used a map.

Now, there are 31N subsets because for each cow, you can create 31 combinations of favorite flavors. For example, Cow 1's favorite flavors of ice cream were 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So the different subsets were:

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}  {1, 3, 0, 0, 0}  {2, 5, 0, 0, 0}  {1, 2, 5, 0, 0}
{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}  {1, 4, 0, 0, 0}  {1, 3, 4, 0, 0}  {2, 3, 5, 0, 0}
{1, 2, 3, 0, 0}  {1, 5, 0, 0, 0}  {1, 3, 5, 0, 0}  {3, 4, 5, 0, 0}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 0}  {2, 3, 0, 0, 0}  {2, 3, 4, 0, 0}  {1, 2, 3, 5, 0}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  {2, 4, 0, 0, 0}  {2, 4, 5, 0, 0}  {1, 3, 4, 5, 0}
{2, 3, 4, 5, 0}  {2, 0, 0, 0, 0}  {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}  {4, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{5, 0, 0, 0, 0}  {3, 4, 0, 0, 0}  {3, 5, 0, 0, 0}  {4, 5, 0, 0, 0}
{1, 4, 5, 0, 0}  {1, 2, 4, 0, 0}  {1, 2, 4, 5, 0}
```

As you can see, there are 31 subsets. (This is because there are 2^5 = 32 sets that can be made, including an empty set. 32 - 1 = 31.) Since N ≤ 50,000, you can generate 31N subsets. After scanning through the input, the code generated the subsets for each cow and added them to a map:

```
map<S5, int> subsets;
```

They mapped each combination to the number of times it was seen. Some examples of entries for the sample input would be:

```
{

[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 2],    # 2 cows, Cow 1 and Cow 2 both like flavor 1
[{8, 10, 0, 0, 0}, 2],   # 2 cows, Cow 2 and Cow 3 both like flavors 8 and 10
[{50, 60, 80, 0, 0}, 1], # 1 cow, Cow 4 liked flavors 50, 60, 80
# and so on...

}
```

Finally, based the number of nonzero numbers in the subset, the algorithm applies the inclusion-exclusion principle. It simply iterates through all 31N subsets, and either adds or subtracts the count stored in the map for that subset. (If it was 1, 3, or 5 nonzero numbers the counts were added; else they were subtracted.) It then subtracts this answer from N * (N-1) / 2 to output the number of pairs of cows that aren't compatible.

I hope this explanation helps! Good luck for future contests!

Answer (score 0):

There are *31N* distinct subsets because each cow has five possible flavor choices. Specifically, this line explains the subsets:

> we can explicitly generate all the subsets of flavors where at least
>   one cow likes all the flavors in that subset

The way to do that is to iterate over all *N* cows then construct the power set of flavors that they like, excluding the empty set. There are `2^5` sets in the power set, so removing the empty set results in 31. Therefore, there are *31N* sets total.

An example is quite helpful here, taking the sample input:

```
4
1 2 3 4 5       # Cow 0
1 2 3 10 8      # Cow 1
10 9 8 7 6      # Cow 2
50 60 70 80 90  # Cow 3
```

The subsets will be:

```
{
  {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, ..., {2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},    # Cow 0
  {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, ..., {2, 3, 10, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 10, 8},  # Cow 1
  ...
}
```

Each cow generates 31 subsets. From there, the algorithm counts the number of cows that generate a specific subset (for example, note that `{1}` is generated by both cow 0 and 1, we just keep track of how many cows generate each subset), and applies inclusion-exclusion based on the subset size.

Nice problem, I used to do USACO and they had really interesting problems which still stand out amongst the "clever" interview questions a lot of companies give. :)